# Reloading a local variable in ASM

Tags: java, validation, bytecode

I am trying to retrieve the name of a class implementing a Java interface and then using this name as a key in a data structure to retrieve some code metrics about the class. Here is what I have done:

```
public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {

   int methodOwner = _lvs.newLocal(Type.getType("Ljava/lang/String;"));

   if (opcode == Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE) {

        // some code to pop the operand stack and
        // get to the object whose method is being called

        // retrieving the name of the class
        int callingObj = _lvs.newLocal(Type.getType(Object.class));
        this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, callingObj);
        this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, callingObj);
        this.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Object", "getClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;");
        this.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Class", "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
        this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, methodOwner);           
        this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, callingObj);

        /// (1)
        /// some code using the methodOwner ....
        /// something like the following
        /// this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, methodOwner);

        /// code to reconstruct the operand stack 
        /// for the method to be invoked
   }

   super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);

   if (opcode == Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE) {
        /// (2)
        /// some more code using the methodOwner  .....
        ///
        /// this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, methodOwner);
   }
}
```

If I comment out code snippets in block (2) from the code above, it works. However when I try to access "methodOwner" in block (2), I receive the following verification error indicating that the string object is gone missing. I can't understand why.

```
  org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Error at instruction 813: Expected an object reference, but found .
```

Since calling **"super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);"** pops the object whose interface method is called, I can't get a reference to it again. I tried keeping a second copy of the object in another variable but same problem occurs.

I wonder if you have any clue on what is wrong here and if you can give me some advice.

thanks very much for your help

Comment: One thing I should add here is that adding the variable to the method works in the first place as the code in block (1) executes without any problem. It is just after calling **super.visitMethodInsn** that access to the newly added variables gets lost.

Answer (score 3):

One very, very simple piece of advise. What I usually do when instrument code is
write the logic in plain java in a static method and call the method.

for instance

```
  class ZZZ{
    public static Object handleIntefaceCall(Object callee){
     //process
     return callee;
    }
  }
```

if the interface has no parameters all you need is call the static method and that is a single line of code

```
visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "pack/ZZZ", "handleIntefaceCall", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");  
super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
```

If there is a single parameter (but not long/double) you have to add a swap instruction before and after the call.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @bestsss. You are right. I should do it for obj.getClass().getName() and make it cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Your visitor implementation should extend the LocalVariableSorter class and you should call super.visitXXX on itself instead of mixing up visit calls between instance lvs and this.

The problem is that you are calling newLocalVar on one visitor and then using this variable slot in another visitor which doesn't knov about this variable. If this class already extends LocalVariableSorter then you should either replace lvs.xxx() cals with this.xxx() or other way around, but there should not be two visitors interleaved.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the reply. My visitor is already extending the MethodAdapter, so I am using LocalVariableSorter through delegation and I have already chained the LVS to the adapter for the class whose methods are being analyzed. It is more like how it is explained in pages 64 and 65 of the ASM manual. What do you suggest?